# How to get date and total date in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to query my SQL Server database to get recent dates, and number of entries per date.

My effort is (where _dc is my DataContext)

```
var result = (from d in this._dc.MyTable
                      where d.DateTime >= fromDate
                      group d by d.DateTime into g
                      select g.FirstOrDefault()).ToDictionary(a => a.DateTime, a => a.Id);
```

This produces results but, it produces a `Dictionary` with the `DateTime` and the `Id`. The `Id` is incorrect, I did that just for testing

The data my effort produces is

```
Dictionary<01/01/2015 10:09:33, 1>
Dictionary<01/01/2015 11:55:12, 2>
Dictionary<02/01/2015 08:11:45, 3>
Dictionary<03/01/2015 10:10:14, 4>
Dictionary<03/01/2015 12:00:32, 5>
```

The data is I would like to be returned is (note unique date as it ignores the time)

```
Dictionary<01/01/2015, 2>
Dictionary<02/01/2015, 1>
Dictionary<03/01/2015, 3>
Dictionary<04/01/2015, 4>
Dictionary<05/01/2015, 3>
```

Where the left is the date of entry, and the right is the total accumulated visits.

I tried things like

```
.ToDictionary(a => a.DateTime, a => a.DateTime.Sum()); //compiler issue
```

I'm lost, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the grouping itself as input for the dictionary:

```
(from d in this._dc.MyTable
                  where d.DateTime >= fromDate
                  group d by DbFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateTime) into g
                  select g)
.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

With Entity Framework < v6, `EntityFunctions` should be used in stead of `DbFunctions`.

Comment: Thanks for this but sadly, the same issue persists... I think the fault is my Database is DateTime where as I want to do this grouping based upon the date only... I'm sorry, my original post wasn't clear :(

Comment: `group d by d.DateTime.Date` may do this, but I'm not sure if this will translate well to SQL. With LINQ-to-SQL it will.

Comment: It failed, but this all helped. I used `group d by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d.DateTime) into g `

Comment: Yes, with EF < v6 that's the way to do it. Always good to tag the kind of LINQ you work with.